# Matching string which might contain whitespace when using Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I need a PowerShell script that will check whether specific user is a part of certain group or not and if the user is part of any of those groups.

But ,it does not correctly working. I am assuming there is an issue regarding `$_ -match 'CN=IT Tool ((TST) Users|(PROD) Users)'`  Also there are whitespaces for below security groups.

Lastly ,I want to get an output via Export-CSV.

There are two groups :

```
IT Tool (TST) Users
IT Tool (PROD) Users
```

SCRIPT:

```
$csv = import-csv "c:\tmp\lists.csv"


foreach ($v in $csv) {
    $userinput = $v.userinput
Get-ADUser -Identity $userinput -Properties EmailAddress, MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
    $testgroups = $_.MemberOf | Where-Object { $_ -match 'CN=IT Tool ((TST) Users|(PROD) Users)' }  
    if ($testgroups) {
        # the user is a member of group IT_Test and/or IT_Prod, get the names of these groups for this user
        $groups = foreach ($grp in $testgroups) { (Get-ADGroup -Identity $grp).Name }
        $_ | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, @{Name = 'MemberOf'; Expression = {$groups -join ', '}}
    }
    else {
        # the user is not a member of any IT_Group
        $_ | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, @{Name = 'MemberOf'; Expression = {'Not a member of any Group'}}
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You need to escape the literal parentheses in the group names: `$_ -match 'CN=IT Tool (\(TST\) Users|\(PROD\) Users),'`. Pattern could also be simplified to `'CN=IT Tool \((TST|PROD)\) Users,'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  wow thanks man!  Lastly ,I want to get an output via Export-CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape any literal `(` or `)` in the group name since these characters will otherwise be interpreted as grouping constructs:

```
$testgroups = $_.MemberOf | Where-Object { $_ -match 'CN=IT Tool (\(TST\) Users|\(PROD\) Users)' }
```

Since the `TST`/`PROD` part is the only thing that varies between the two possible group names, you can simplify the pattern further:

```
$testgroups = $_.MemberOf | Where-Object { $_ -match 'CN=IT Tool \((TST|PROD)\) Users)' }
```

To export the results to a CSV, simply collect the output from the loop to a variable, and then pipe the variable contents to `Export-Csv`:

```
$results = foreach($v in $csv) {
  # ...
}

$results |Export-Csv -Path path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```